# ERD Can a weak entity be involved in a ISA relation?

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship, erd

As title says, can a weak entity have subtypes? I have this situation: The test depends on the timestamp and the tester that executed the test (So Test is a weak entity), and I can have 2 types of tests.

[image]
Is it reasonable or there are some mistakes?

Comment: Unrelated: *@GhostCat I don't know, you can tell me what other info you need. You can see the situation as a Recipe for a dish, but you have 40 ingredients" ... because, as I said: in the end, you need a solution that works for YOUR specific situation. There is no magic in programming, if you have 40 parameters, you have to deal with them *somehow*. But to decide which sort of *somehow* works for you ... most often depends on understanding the whole picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say that `test` is [weak entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_entity) it means that it does not have an own unique identifier (e.g. a surrogate key) but that it needs to combine some of its attributes as partial keys together with the key of the entities it depends on, i.e. `timestamp` and a `tester`.

This situation is not incompatible with an `IsA` subtyping.
If `test_1` IsA `test`, then, every instance of `test_1` is also an instance of `test`.  As a consequence, a `test_1` must inherit allo the attributes of a `test`.  Moreover, the key that uniquely identify a  `test` must also be a key of `test_1` .

`test_1` would therefore share the same keys.  Consequently it would also be a weak entity.